# SSRS 2012 PDF Email subscription presents a different value than when run locally. How can this be?

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

If I let SSRS 2012 subscription email my report, a cell that finds the AVG of values in the report will be shown as "NaN". If I run the report myself it looks fine, if I then create a PDF from that report it too looks fine. Only when the report is run from the subscription is the value changed to "NaN".
Where do I look for a problem like this? What is different between the subscription running the report and my running it locally?

Comment: How are you running the report manually? Through the Report Manager website or through BIDS?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I am new to this forum and expected an email when a comment was posted. When run manually it worked fine, when run as a subscription and then either emailed or sent to a file share, this issue occurs. I can run the report manually at anytime and get proper output. I can set up a subscription for any time and I will see the error.